# SSAS Show Monthly or quarterly data based on user selected date

Tags: time, ssas, mdx, business-intelligence

One of our client wants to visualize data based on the date. We have our own reporting tool which connects to `SSAS` Cubes.

**Clients wants to choose one date, and based on the date chosen we have to show data for the last 36 months on `Monthly` basis anything prior to 36 months must be on `Quarterly` basis. Any help achieving this is appreciated.**

The output will be similar to this:

> So for example if we choose today's date, the Date band should display
>   monthly data till Apr-13, anything prior to that should be shown on a
>   quarterly basis.

Thanks and regards,

Sheetal

Comment: please either add your attempted mdx to the question, or maybe better to delete the mdx tag

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create calculated columns in your report which will show data based on the selected date.